# Cashing in a IRA from Puerto Rico

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, withdrawal, puerto-rico

My wife was born and worked in PR prior to our marriage over 20 years ago. She is now 60 years old. She has a IRA in PR. If she cashed out the money do we need to show this as income on our yearly taxes here in the US?  We wanted to roll it over but I don’t think we are able. If she deposits the money in a bank in PR can we write a check from PR and pay for things in the US such as college tuition?

Comment: Might have to move back to PR first